# Enum as variable's property in go

Tags: go, enums

Let's say I have something like this:

```
const (
    FOO int = iota
    BAR
    BAZ
)
```

And I can access to variables by `FOO`, `BAR` and so on. But storing a big amount of constants in one namespace isn't good so I'm trying to hide this enum in structure or something like that so I can get value by typing `actions.FOO` in same namespace. I've tried many ways but didn't find anything like that. I would like to mention that easiest workaround, in this case, will be anonymous structure but I wanna keep auto indexing with `iota`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GOLANG "Namespaced" enums?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459224/golang-namespaced-enums)

Comment: I've seen this question but in my case, I'm writing all code in one namespace.

Comment: Only possible solutions I can think of are the answers in the question mentioned by Tim.

Comment: @AJPennster, according to answers there is only way is to store enums in another package, is there is no way of storing enumerable in same namespace as property of structure for example?

Comment: There is a second answer there with the use of types. The constants will still be globally available to the package but only if you use the type associated with it. That is the closest answer I can think of to what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to assign some sort of enumerable behind the property without creating the separate package that I found is to use anonymous structure.

```
type someType int

var ConstantsList = struct {
   FOO, BAR, BAZ someType
}{1, 2, 3}
```

There are few downsides of using it, it's not immutable, and doesn't have auto increment.